# the most efficient way to calculate average value

Tags: shell, unix, math, awk

I have a file, which looks like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... 2465m
id porttitor libero mauris at magna... 1m
istique pretium tincidunt. V...1200m
...
```

I want to calculate (using unix commands, awk, grep etc.) sum of trailing number, I mean (2465 + 1 + 1200 + ...) / NUMBER_OF_LINES. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: could your line look like `foo...bar... foo200m`? I mean non-blank char before the first digit?

Comment: No, there is always space

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This makes it:

```
$ awk '{sum+=$NF+0} END{print "total sum is " sum " and average " sum/NR}' file
total sum is 3666 and average 1222
```

`$NF` stands for the last word of every line. It uses `$NF+0` so that the trailing `m` and other characters are not taken into account. Then it keeps the sum in `sum` variable, that is printed at the end.
Finally it prints the average, taken dividing the `sum` by `NR`, which has the value of number of lines processed.

Comment: your command actually prints out an incorrect average of 822 for the OP's input.

Comment: you changed OP's example, added a space, didn't u? ;)

Comment: @dogbane 822 would be 3666/4 and I took just three first lines, as the `...` would be filled with other content.

Comment: @Kent yes :) I assumed what you commented under the question

Answer (score 4):

I would do this:

```
grep -oP '\d+(?=m\s*$)' file|awk '{_+=$0}END{printf "Avg: %0.2f\n",_/NR}'
```

it has two processes, grep and awk, but it works the case that the number column/field starts with non-digit char. like:

```
foo123 456 ffffff100m
xbar 222 444 bbbbb200m
234 df343 xxxxxx300m
```

with the above example, it outputs :

```
Avg: 200.00
```

with your example it outputs:

```
Avg: 1222.00
```

Comment: @fedorqui thx, he didn't describe the Q well. the `...` is confusing. if there were spaces, yours and konsoleboxs answer are better.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{sum+=$NF}END{printf "Average: %0.2f\n",sum/NR}' file
```

Input:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... 2465m
id porttitor libero mauris at magna... 1m
istique pretium tincidunt. V...1200m
```

Output:

```
Average: 822.00
```

Some parts actually didn't have spaces and does not work with `FS=" ."` so you really had to convert the string.

```
awk '{t=$NF;gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",t);sum+=t}END{printf "Average: %0.2f\n",sum/NR}'
```

Output:

```
Average: 1222.00
```

Comment: the result is not correct,  `echo "(2465+1+1200)/3"|bc` gives `1222` on my laptop. the big "V" in last line is the problem. your awk works only if the `NF` beginning with the number.

Comment: what if the last col is `foo300bar300m` ?

Comment: @Kent I considered that but I don't think that would be an occasion.

Comment: I agree. perhaps your initial attempt was exactly OP's looking for. he just didn't describe the question well.

Comment: Yeah I actually was the one who had the right answer for the average first :) fedorqui's solution only had it with the sum.

Comment: +1 for your speed... 

@fedorqui is always very fast, happy to see someone is faster then him. :D

Comment: In fact I was faster in this question, @Kent :)